# Is there a way to keep Android camera recording going through multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-camera, surfaceview

I would like to make an application in which the front camera is being recorded throughout the full lifecycle of the application - from the time that it is started by the user to the time that it is terminated.

I am aware that I need to create a `SurfaceView` and use the `MediaRecorder` class to set up recording. I would like to pass this `SurfaceView` between `Activities` without having to initialize it in each new `Activity`. The goal of this is not having to interrupt the camera recording.

Is this possible? I am aware that I can record via the camera application as described in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html) tutorial, but I would like to have full control of the `MediaRecorder` and thus cannot use this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a `SurfaceView` in the first `Activity` of the application like so:

```
mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1, 1));
mSurfaceView.setPadding(-1, -1, 0, 0);
vg.addView(mSurfaceView);
```

I added the view to the main `ViewGroup` of the activity and made sure that it does not show up on the screen.

I then set the `SurfaceHolder` of this `SurfaceView` as the preview display for the `Camera`. I also set the `Surface` of the `SurfaceHolder` as the preview display of `MediaRecorder`.

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
// ... other code goes here ...
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
// ... other code goes here ...
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
```

Finally, I persisted the instance of `Camera` and `MediaRecorder` in the subclass of `Application`. This made sure that the `SurfaceView` would not be garbage collected, since it is referenced by other objects that have references for the duration of the application's lifecycle. This allowed me to record on the camera through multiple `Activities` until I called the `stop()` function on the instance of `MediaRecorder`.

```
((CameraTest) getApplication()).setCamera(mCamera);
((CameraTest) getApplication()).setMediaRecorder(mMediaRecorder);
```

---

EDIT: Unfortunately, this does not work on the Asus Nexus 7. It does work on the Samsung Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass SurfaceView between activities as its not parcelable. So camera recording will get interrupted in case of activities. You can use fragments though, keep code for recording in activity class and on navigation keep changing fragments.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I will not be able to use this solution. My specification does not allow me to use fragments instead of activities. I would like the recording code to be potentially used in multiple applications.


EDIT: If the first activity is always around, would I be able to just store a `SurfaceView` on it, add a reference to it in the `Application` class, and refer to it from `Activities` that may be launched later?

Comment: How doesnt it allow to use fragment? Is it because of target api level? if it is, you can use support v4.
I think that can work, but you will have to recording code in a separate thread, UI thread doesnt work for background activities I think. I am not sure about it.

Comment: I am writing more of an SDK for others to use in their apps, thus I have no control over whether they use fragments or full on activities.